# Recompile PHP *nix

Tags: php, unix

I'm a total newb to *nix in all forms so assume I know nothing about it.

I've been trying to use a php function set called "ZipArchive". It says I need to recompile php with the --enable-zip option.

Now "recompile php" scares me. Does that re-install it!? Does it clear all previous settings so if I do this then any settings done prior will be wiped? Or is there a way to add on this one option?

Seems a bit much for a re-installation to add a module when on a windows server it is just add a line to the .ini file :\

Many thanks to anyone who can clear up this matter for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you won't need to really re-compile. The zip module is probably available as a simple package install from your distro's package repositories. What linux distro are you running?

Comment: Linux 2.6.24-gentoo-r3-comtrance on x86_64 is what the webmin says

Comment: It's been a while since I touched gentoo, but all you need to do if I recall is re-emerge php5 with the "zip" USE flag. After doing that, restart apache2 and you should be good to go.

Comment: " re-emerge php5 " ?? If this is right then that is perfect! :|

Answer (score 0):

Type "php -i | grep -i configure" and the configure line that was used will be shown. Now, you just need to use that configure line and add the "--enable-zip" and recompile you php. "php -i" shows a list of useful information about what's installed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i'm looking at the info from php-i now! wowa.. lots of stuff

Comment: php -i | grep -i configure produced a command but... if I reinstall do I lose anything? I mean, is there a way to changed things after that install/configure was used (in other words, will it break anything!?)